# Logistic Regression only recognizing predominant classes

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, logistic-regression

I am participating in the Kaggle San Francisco Crime competition and i am currently trying o number of different classifiers to test benchmark performances. I am using a LogisticRegressionClassifier from sklearn, without any parameter tuning and I noticed from sklearn.metrict.classification_report that it is only predicting the predominant classses,i.e. the classes which have the highest number of occurrences in my training set.

Intuition tells me that this has to parameter tuning, but I am not sure which parameters I have to tweek in order to make the classifier more aware of less predominant classes ( LogisticRegressionClassifier has quite a few ). At the moment it is predicting only 3 classes from 38 or smth like that so it definitely needs improvement.

Any ideas?

Comment: You should post some of your code, the piece that you think is more relevant. It provides information that you may have not communicated.

Comment: What happens if you use the `class_weight = 'balanced'` parameter?

Comment: Also, look at GridSearchCV and similar classes, maybe they will help to find good hyperparameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your model is classifying only predominant classes then you are facing problem of imbalance classes. Here are some [good reads](http://machinelearningmastery.com/tactics-to-combat-imbalanced-classes-in-your-machine-learning-dataset/) to tackle this in machine learning.

Logistic Regression is a binary classifier and uses one-vs-all or one-vs-one technique for multiclass classification, which is not good if you have higher number of output classes (33 in your case). Try using other classifier. For a start , use [softmax classifier](http://ufldl.stanford.edu/tutorial/supervised/SoftmaxRegression/) which is an extension of logistic classifier having support for multi-class classification. In [scikit learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html), set `multi_class` variable as `multinomial` to use softmax regression.

Other way to improve your model could be using GridSearch for parameter tuning.

On a side note, I would recommend you to use other models as well.